# magento 2.2.0 reindex through command is not working

Tags: reindex, magento2.2.0

I have setup **magento 2.2.0** version and set index to update on scheduel. When I remove category from product and run **`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`** command it's reindex successfully but when I check in front end it's not take any effect.

Anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clear the catches.

Comment: @Chirag Parmar i have clear cache still it's not working.it's magento 2.2.0 default bug.